# Draw lines from points to points not by lon/lat in mapbasic

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

How to draw lines from points to points not by lon/lat?

What I need is a cross connection with cable like the image below:
I have N input and M output points

[image]

Comment: Have you tried CONNDOTS.mbx http://www.mapinfotools.com/index.php?option=com_sobi2&sobi2Task=sobi2Details&catid=10&sobi2Id=249&Itemid=53

Comment: I think Conndots.mbx draws lines base on lon/lat what i need is based not by lon/lat

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you have a table with the cross connections, right?

If so, you can loop this table and for each record:

Get the RowID of current record:

```
nRowID = CROSS_CONNECTIONS.ROWID
```

Select the matching record from the input table, extract the CentroidX() and CentroidX()

```
nID = CROSS_CONNECTIONS.INPUT_ID
Select CentroidX(OBJ) "X", CentroidY(OBJ) "Y" 
   From InputTable
   Where ID = nID
   Into __CENTROID NoSelect
Fetch First From __CENTROID
fInputX = __CENTROID.X
fInputY = __CENTROID.Y
```

Select the matching record from the output table, extract the CentroidX() and CentroidX()

```
nID = CROSS_CONNECTIONS.OUTPUT_ID
Select CentroidX(OBJ) "X", CentroidY(OBJ) "Y" 
   From OutputTable
   Where ID = nID
   Into __CENTROID NoSelect
Fetch First From __CENTROID
fOutputX = __CENTROID.X
fOutputY = __CENTROID.Y
```

Create a new line using CreateLine() where the coordinates are the those you got from the input and output records

```
oLine = CreateLine(fInputX, fInputY, fOutputX, fOutputY)
```

And finally assign the new line ot the current record in the CROSSCONNECTION table:

```
Update CROSSCONNECTION
   Set OBJ = oLine
   Where ROWID = nRowID
```

You loop could look like this:

```
'**Let's set the coordsys to match the Input Table
Set CoordSys Table InputTable
'**And now the loop thru the table of Cross Connections
Fetch First From CROSSCONNECTION
Do UNTIL EOT(CROSSCONNECTION)
   '**Here you paste the code from above

   Fetch Next From CROSSCONNECTION
Loop
```